# Dynamically set the action name in MVC3 cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datatables, dynamic-programming

I have an MVC3 project in which I create a dynamic jQuery DataTable. I added a custom attribute to my table called "GetDataFunc" which contains the action name on the controller side.
I want to use this attribute's value when defining the DataTable, but the @Url.Action won't accept a parameter (as oppose to a string) in the first parametes.

My code:

```
        var table = document.getElementById('UsersTbl');

        if (table.hasAttribute("GetDataFunc")) {

            var func = table.GetDataFunc;

            var oTable = $('#MyTbl').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action(func, "MyPages")',
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aoColumns": cols,
                "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Search all columns:" },
                "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    totalRecords = oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay();
                }
            });

        }
```

When I try to run my program I get: 

*The name 'func' does not exist in the current context*

How can I dynamically define which function to call on the controller side?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just use a string? If you know the method name then use it with `Url.Action`.

Comment: Because I don't know it. I will get the function name from an outer XML file. As I said, it's a Dynamic DataTable. You are right that if I have only one table on page, there won't be such an issue, but if I have more than one table, I won't be able to tell which function should I call.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix JavaScript and C#. Don't.

Instead of `'@Url.Action(func, "MyPages")'` only use javascript to determine the url you need to go. At the end of the day `@Url.Action` generates you a string with url for the controller/action.